# Cite Command with a Customised Field for Biblatex

Tags: macros, biblatex, biber

I am writing a PhD and my mentor wants me to use a specific short form of citation in the footnotes and long one in the bibliography at the end of the work. So basically I need to have three short fields instead of classical two (`shorttitle` and `shortauthor`).

I need to find a way to add `shortseries` which I would use in footnotes.

This is what I use so far for the two fields:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{myshort}{%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \ifboolexpr{ test{\ifnameundef{shortauthor}} 
                or test {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}}}
      {\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
      {\printnames{shortauthor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{shorttitle}\isdot}%
       \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver{}{myshort}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

This is what this produces:

> See Iust., De Triph. S. 11.

I need to either find a way to introduce another bibliography field which would be called `shortseries` or I need to find a way to use some of the optional fields in the incollection like `note` which I never use to take over this function.

Here is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
     @incollection{iustinus1997,
            Address = {Berlin/New York},
            Author = {{Iustinus Martyr}},
            Title = {Iustini Martyris dialogus cum Tryphone},
            Editor = {Miroslav Marcovich},
            Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
            Series = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
            Shortauthor = {Iust.},
            Shorttitle = {De Tryph.},
            Shortseries = {PG},
            Volume = {47},
            Year = {1997}}
    \end{filecontents} 
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    \DeclareBibliographyDriver{myshort}{%
        \usebibmacro{begentry}%
        \ifboolexpr{ test{\ifnameundef{shortauthor}}
                    or test {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}}}
          {\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
          {\printnames{shortauthor}%
           \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
           \printfield{shorttitle}\isdot}%
           \usebibmacro{finentry}%
        }
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibfootnote]
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {\usedriver{}{myshort}}
      {\multicitedelim}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
    \begin{document}
    \blindtext \mycite[See][S. 11]{iustinus1997}
    \blindtext
    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

and when i use: `\mycite[See][11]{iustinus1997}` this is what I need to get as an end-result:

> See *Iust.*, De Tryph., in: PG 47, S. 11.

Anyone got the idea how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use one of the `user` fields. Let's say `usera`.

The following is essentially the code posted above, but using `usera` rather than `shortseries`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
 @incollection{iustinus1997,
        Address = {Berlin/New York},
        Author = {{Iustinus Martyr}},
        Title = {Iustini Martyris dialogus cum Tryphone},
        Editor = {Miroslav Marcovich},
        Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
        Series = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
        Shortauthor = {Iust.},
        Shorttitle = {De Tryph.},
        Usera = {PG},
        Volume = {47},
        Year = {1997}}
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, hyperref=true]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{myshort}{%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \ifboolexpr{ test{\ifnameundef{shortauthor}}
                or test {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}}}
      {\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
      {\printnames{shortauthor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{shorttitle}\isdot}%
       \iffieldundef{usera}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}% or \newunit
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}% or \printfield{volume}
       \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }
\DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver{}{myshort}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\begin{document}
\blindtext \mycite[See][S. 11]{iustinus1997}
\blindtext
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image: Image of footnote as requested]

This should also work (1) If there is no "Usera" field, and (2) if there is no volume number. A variation would be to use the "usual" way of writing volumes, which I have suppressed, and to have a period (rather than a comma) before the "in:". I've shown this code in comments, above. If we replace those lines we get.

[image]

By all means play around with the driver to get things to your liking. Be careful not to introduce stray spaces, which are the most common source of infuriation in driver-writing. If in doubt, comment the end of every line.

You could use your "shortseries" field if you wanted to using a source mapping, but it's probably overkill.

Comment: Thank you for this! It works great except that it produces ) after some volume numbers (not always) like this: Vgl. Cyr. H., catech., in: PG 33), S. 448-449 (16). Any idea why?

Comment: None! How mysterious. Is it always the same entries that do this?

Comment: I figured it out what it is! The thing that makes begentry errors and probably messes with ) is my biblatex style I am using which is Historische Zeitschrift Style.

Comment: Some of the things here are messing with everything: \usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}

Comment: Could be. I assumed your style was as posted. I can't look now but I'll see if I can track down the issue tomorrow. Incidentally you should use `\addbibresource` not `bibliography` too.

Comment: Ok I added my style to the original MWE now. This does reproduces the "begentry" error but not the ")" which is also in my work random but it also has to be connected with historische-zeitschrift style. Thanks for taking your time to help Paul!

Comment: Another thing occurred to me: Is there a way to make this works only for the first time I cite something with \mycite ? What I mean is when I use the command \mycite for the second time somewhere in the work I need it to treat it as the normal \footcite.